# Disable Space between for last item on FlatView

Tags: react-native, layout, styles

I'm facing an issue with my flatview in react-native,

I would like to display by row some item using a flatview with space-between property on the columnWrapperStyle property but here is the result :

[image]

Here is the code :

```js
<FlatList style={styles.list}
  numColumns={3}
  data={prescriptions}

  renderItem={({ item, index, separators }) => (
    <Card image={item.image} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  columnWrapperStyle={styles.row} 
/>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: normalizeVertical(5)
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
});
```

I would like to put my last item next to the previous one, how to handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `justifyContent: 'flex-start'` instead of `justifyContent: "space-between"` in your `row` style.

For example :

```
row: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'flex-start' // add this
}
```

Comment: Yes, for margin you have to add it.